# Remove tonymacx86 logo in Hackintosh

Tags: macos, finder

I have OS X (hackintosh) installed in virtualbox on ubuntu linux host.  I used iAtkos ML8 distribution with MultiBeast to get the right drivers.  Everything works perfectly fine, however somewhere along the way MultiBeast modified some settings to display the tonymacx86 logo (red apple with eyes) as a generic background of some sort (or foreground, depending on your point of view) - see the picture below.

[image]

This red apple is ALWAYS there, regardless of what other apps I use - displayed ABOVE any other apps, including XCode, iTunes, Settings, etc.  For the life of me, I can't track where this apple is residing.  I just want to get rid of it, as it's very obtrusive and often makes the text on the window difficult to read.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from asking Tony or digging around in whatever text he modified to add this watermark to remind you of the work he cut out for you, you just need to create your own Hackintosh image using freely available tools and retail Mac OS X images (Mavericks is free).

These two articles have the information you need to create your own Mac OS X install for virtual box.

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-create-an-os-x-mavericks-usb-installation-drive-1450280026
http://forums.appleinsider.com/t/159955/howto-create-bootable-mavericks-iso